# How to select data from local database when it is not present in remote database

Tags: .net, vb.net, datatable, sqlcommand, sqldataadapter

Is it possible to select data rows from local database when those rows are not present in remote database?
I wrote a code, but it doesn't work: `conlocal` is the local database connection, and `conremote` is the remote database connection; `Dim` command as

```
sqlcommand =  new sqlcommand ("select id from table", conlocal, "where id not in table",conremote)
```

Comment: Not with one query, but you can retrieve data from remote database if there are no required data, execute another query against local database.

Comment: I can retrieve data from remote db, but how can i compare if there is no data which are in my local db?? Thanks for your rapid reply

Comment: If you need compare two datasets, load both and compare them in the memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comments in line

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    'Get ID's from remote database
    Dim RemoteDT As New DataTable
    Using cn As New SqlConnection("Your remote connection string")
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("Select Id From [RemoteTableName];", cn)
            cn.Open()
            RemoteDT.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
    End Using
    'Put the Ids into an array
    Dim IdsInRemote As Integer() = (RemoteDT.AsEnumerable().[Select](Function(x) x.Field(Of Integer)("Id"))).ToArray()
    'Change the array to a single string that can be used in the Select statement
    Dim Remotes As String = String.Join(",", IdsInRemote)
    Dim LocalDT As New DataTable
    Using cn As New SqlConnection("Your local connection string")
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand($"Select Id From [LocalTableName] Where Id Not In ({Remotes});", cn)
            cn.Open()
            LocalDT.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
    End Using
    For Each row As DataRow In LocalDT.Rows
        Debug.Print(row(0).ToString)
    Next
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

For vb.net versions prior to version 14 (2015)

```
Using cmd As New SqlCommand(String.Format("Select Id From [LocalTableName] Where Id Not In ({0});", Remotes), cn)
```

**EDIT**

Explanation of `RemoteDT.AsEnumerable().[Select](Function(x) x.Field(Of Integer)("Id")).ToArray()`

`.AsEnumerable` is a method of a `DataTable` that returns an enumerable of `DataRow`.

Select will pick rows from the enumerable that match the criteria we provide. In this case we are providing a Function with a parameter x.

x refers to the elements of the of the `IEnumerable`, in this case a `DataRow`. You could name this anything you want. The variable would only be seen inside this inline function so a simple name is OK. A descriptive name would be fine too but since it is seen inline only it really isn't necessary.

So the function checks every x in the enumerable (every DataRow) and returns only the values in Field of Integers called "Id"

**My error here!**

Finally the enumerable is converted to an array. I neglected to add the parenthesis around the enumerable that is to be converted to an array.

```
(RemoteDT.AsEnumerable().[Select](Function(x) x.Field(Of Integer)("Id"))).ToArray()
```

**EDIT**

Since I have now found out that Id is a String

```
    'Put the Ids into an array
    'Change the datatype of the array and the field to String
    Dim IdsInRemote As String() = (RemoteDT.AsEnumerable().[Select](Function(x) x.Field(Of String)("Id"))).ToArray()
    'Change the array to a single string that can be used in the Select statement
    'Add single quotes to the .Join so Sql Server will interpret as String
    Dim Remotes As String = String.Join("','", IdsInRemote)
    'Put a single quote on the beginning and end of the Remotes string
    'The Join does not do this
    Remotes = "'" & Remotes & "'"
    'You can inspect the string in the immediate window
    Debug.Print(Remotes)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I have tried it. But getting an error at Using cmd As New SqlCommand($"Select Id From [LocalTableName] Where Id Not In ({Remotes});", cn). Another thing is my column name is URN, DATA type is varchar 17.

Comment: The interpolated string requires Vb.net 14 or greater which was available in 2015. I will edit the answer to show the equivalent String.Format. If this is not the problem please tell me what the error is.

Comment: Thanks @MARY. Now I am using VS 2019, but while debugging getting error "Specified cast is not valid".  I have a question , why you are using "x"? Some info: column name is URN and data type is varchar(17). So how to convert varchar(17) data type to integer?

Comment: @DIPANKAR I have added an explanation  (see my new EDIT) and corrected a big error I made. If this doesn't work then, perhaps, the datatype of Id is not an Integer. Let me know how it turns out.

Comment: Still I am getting the same error "Specified cast is not valid". Don't know why..but getting.

Comment: Let's see if the DataTable has rows. Add a line just above the problem line. `MessageBox.Show($"Row Count = {RemoteDT.Rows.Count}")` I tested again and the line runs fine for me.

Comment: Another thought. Is the Id field of type Int in the database?

Comment: No. id field of type is varchar(17)

Comment: Well, that changes things.

Comment: `Dim IdsInRemote As String() = (RemoteDT.AsEnumerable().[Select](Function(x) x.Field(Of String)("Id"))).ToArray()`

Comment: Now it can change array to string successfully. but after that it is giving another error. "Incorrect syntax near 'ID'".

Comment: Dear @MARY you just made me cry. Now every thing is working fine like butter. Thank you so much Mary. I just made some changes in code, after getting all id's in one array I fill the destination using sql data adapter fill method. Please see the edit.

Comment: I am very glad it is working. Instead of editing my answer you can either edit you original question or add an answer of your own.